# PHP remove conditional comments which cause DOMXPath fail

Tags: php, domxpath, conditional-comments

conditional comments such as:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><!--> <html lang="hi" class="ie ie6"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

causes

```
$doc->loadHTML($content);   
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
```

does not work properly. any prepared code to remove them?

Comment: works for me .. http://3v4l.org/tNfPX

Comment: what if several of them do exist in a page? i want none IE html only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If parsing the HTML doesn't work then you could use regular expressions, something like this example:

```
$str = "aa<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><!--> <html lang=\"hi\" class=\"ie ie6\"> <!--<![endif]-->bb cc";
$pattern = "/(<!--[if\s[lg]+t\sIE\s[0-9]+\s]><!-->)(.*)(<!--<!\[endif\]-->)/"; 
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);    
echo $str;
```

Or to keep the contents of the conditional tags:

```
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '$2', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: what if between `<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><!-->` and `<!--<![endif]-->` something else is written?